# Your app information could not be saved.Try again.New iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, submit, app-store-connect

[image: This is the question Image]

1. I regenerate all of the certificates, update the version number of the application, but the problem persists.
2. Follow the below steps.
   Go to My Apps Page.
   Remove the Build. Then Save It.
   Re Add your Build. then Save It.
   Now try to Submit It must work.
   I do not know what the reasons are, how to do?Thanks!

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue, and it's a pain. I just wish the developers of this site (iTunes Connect) returned more MEANINGFUL messages, or simply say "check back soon". You're just left with not knowing what to do, blah.

Comment: I've been with Apple Support for over a month with this problem. They keep telling me it's a known issue, and please be patient. Yes, I've tried all the suggestions here, and in this thread below, but nothing has worked. Good thing it's not an important app. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6522670

Comment: None of the answers are work for me. So, I just change the System... And It's Work for me...

Comment: July 29, 2017: the issue is back!

Comment: iTunesConnect has so many bugs that it's unbelieavable. We've had this and many other problems for 2 weeks now and are seriously thinking of simply ditching the iOS platform since they are making developers life hell. They should check how Google does things.

Answer (score 21):

In **Prerelease** section the status of your build should not be "Processing". Just wait some time (10-20 min) after build upload, and it will be ready to use.

Answer (score 9):

I got this problem in Chrome browser. Switching to Safari worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Same thing here... It kept being a problem in Firefox, but as soon as I switched to Safari, it worked immediately on both of my apps that were having the problem.

Comment: "Worked like a charm" - are you serious? Apple should learn how to develop things so they work on major browsers.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. To solve it, the unique thing I had to do was "Clear History and Website Data..." within Safari (version 8.0.3 in my case).

Please, keep in mind that I speak from my experience and that worked for me. I cannot guarantee this as a general rule to fix the problem. Nevertheless I can assure that I tried several alternatives explained here and the one I just described was the solution for me.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment I've just got an official response from Apple:
"- Make sure you are using the latest version of Safari, if not update your browser.
- Log out of iTunes Connect.
- Clear your cookies and website data.
- Log back into iTunes Connect to see if the issue has been resolved.
If you are still encountering the issue, please provide the following:
- Click by click screenshots showing the steps you are taking to receive that error. 
- Screenshots should be fullscreen, in the latest version of Safari, with the URL link showing."

Answer (score 4):

It seems to happen if you are too quick between the build finishing "processing" and it being attached to a version and the version being submitted. I just published two apps in quick succession and the second submission had this problem while the first was fine. The only difference - speed of clicking the submit button.

Logging out and back in made no difference - the "problem" is with the submission.

I removed the just uploaded build from the version and then re-attached it, proceeding as normal to submit the release to Apple with exactly the same build and submission artifacts as before, except this one "saved" and went into the review queue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the strange but working solution.
I had tried submitting the app using Safari browser but it didn't work and showed same error. Submitting the App using Chrome worked for me in the first go...

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck on this too; and have had to work around several other iTunes Connect bugs just to get to this point.  What were Apple thinking by releasing this iTunes Connect version?  It's completely ridden with bugs!

Sorry, I've tried everything I can: Filing a support case with Apple appears to be the only 'solution' at this point.

Comment: I did not do, but the next day, I submitted a success.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Version you have on iTunes Connect and the version you gave in the Info settings in xCode are exactly the same.
I had 1.0.0 in iTunes Connect and 1.0 in xCode and it kept giving me this error message. I changed it to 1.0.0 in xCode and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. just sign out and sign in again. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following issue when submitting a build which was uploaded couple of days ago for test flight testing. Then figured out that the provisioning profile of the application has expired so I renewed the prov profile and downloaded and re-archived the application (by increasing only the build number ) and uploaded and submitted it. And it worked like a charm.

I guess apple need to be specific of these error scenarios

Answer (score 0):

In my case we contacted apple and they said the issue is that it seems that we don’t have a correct certificate generated on developer.apple.com. We use Xcode automatic signing management. **I refreshed correct profiles, rebuilt and I could submit successfully.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried from different system and it got saved

Answer (score 0):

What i did is changed the version and it worked.