# Not able to submit products for inApp-Purchase in iTunes connect in IOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

[image]

Getting this error again and again after adding image and hitting Save button. "Your In-App Purchase information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us."

Comment: is your question duplicated? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861548/your-app-information-could-not-be-saved-try-again-new-itunes-connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861548/your-app-information-could-not-be-saved-try-again-new-itunes-connect)

Comment: I think itunesconnect might be down.  I'm having the same problem

Comment: getting the exact same error, also if adding a new in app purchase with an image already attached, i get an internal server error and the "save" button just hangs indefinitely

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this was rejected as an edit. Anyway:

No, this is not a duplicate. This is about In App Purchases while the question you mentioned is about App status.

I was facing the same problem today, and it seems other people too.

What I tried and didn't work (so please don't put this as a possible answer): 1- I used google chrome + Safari on Mac OS 10.12, no chance. Then I tried private mode (same as delete cookies and history), no chance.

2- I switched to windows 7 computer, chrome + firefox (never used before), no chance.

3- I used Safari on iPad Mini with iOS10, no chance.

4- When posting a new IAP with an attached screenshot image, the save button will load forever and nothing will be saved.

5- I contacted Apple about the problem and gave all details. I am waiting for the solution.

**Edit** : Finally, **it is working again** (October 7th, 8am GMT). I don't know wether contacting Apple solved this or it was solved for every one. I just uploaded the screenshot and saved the In App Purchase, and I am able to submit the app for review.
If it still doesn't work for you, just contact Apple support with the link provided in the error message, and be patient (try to work in another thing, drink a coffee, or go to shopping :) )

Comment: I am having the EXACT same problem since yesterday. Can't add screenshot to existing IAP and can't create a new IAP with screenshot. It's definitely related to the screenshot. Tried everything I could, sent e-mail to Apple, waiting response. Here is a video showing the issue: https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/3k270A101l0V2F1V1t24/itc-iap-error.mp4

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, at least i know others are facing the exact same issue. Waiting for a resolution from apple...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually today i got the success when i had tried from different system,i used the screenshot from iphone5s simulator in 100% resolution and got the success.
But same-thing,i had also tried before putting up this question.

So that means it might be error from apple server as sometimes it just not works.
PFA for screenshot i used:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are resubmitting (for example, after a previous rejection), it seems like this can be caused by adding additional in app purchases.

Our app binary was rejected, we uploaded a new one and while we were at it we added an additional in app purchase to the submission and some extra text to the app review information.  All other in app purchases previously submitted remained "In Review" so we were literally just adding in another to the submission.

We got a 500 Internal Server Error when clicking submit (verified using FireFox dev tools).  We tried Safari, Chrome, Firefox on Mac and PC - all up-to-date. Same behaviour.

We tried removing the extra new in-app purchase (and cut down the extra review text a little) from the submission and it immediately went through without a hitch. YMMV, but worth checking.